# Custom ListView won't show up in the Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I am trying to create a ListView with custom row layout and Adapter in Android Studio. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) but attempted a simpler version to familiarize myself with it. I do not fill data in the ListView from data in JSON format or use any imageloader, I am just trying to use similar format but set the strings' content manually.

I created a `row.xml` with only a simple textfield "name". Then created a simple ListModel to create get and set methods for the string name. Then tried to create and use the custom adapter with the ListModel to place the content in the ListViewActivity. Finally, in the ListViewActivity I tried to define the content of the string name and show it in the view.

I have no errors when running the application, but the listview won't show in the activity. I expected the output to be a single row with "Hiiiii" init. What am I doing wrong?

**list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    android:id="@+id/listviewactivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/challengeslistView"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
```

**ListModel.java**

```
    public class ListModel {

        private  String Name="";

        public ListModel() {

        }

        public ListModel(String name) {
            this.Name = name;


        }

        /*********** Set Methods ******************/

        public void setName(String Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }



        /*********** Get Methods ****************/

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }

    }
```

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView; 
import java.util.List;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ListModel> items;


    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<ListModel> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return items.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.testimage);

        ListModel m = items.get(position);

        // title
        name.setText(m.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**ListViewActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class ListViewActivityextends Activity {

        private List<ListModel> list = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
        private ListView listView;
        private CustomListAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.challenges_view);
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            ListModel listmodel = new ListModel();
            listmodel.setName("Hiiiiii");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private List<ListModel> list = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
```

Your list object will be of size zero. i havnt seen any data initialization for that

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in your adapter getCount method will return its size and it will be zero in your case. Pls check

You should initialize that list with your data. or change the code like this

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            //create your model data
            ListModel listmodel = new ListModel();
            listmodel.setName("Hiiiiii");

            //add your model to the collection
            list.add(listmodel);

            //then you can set your adapter
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Comment: My bad I should have noticed that. Thank  you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your list is empty that is why it is not showing anything.You can handle this in two possible ways.

1. if you know that your array list is of fixed size and it wont update then you can first populate your list and then set the adapter...

   ```
       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
       ListModel listmodel = new ListModel();
       listmodel.setName("Hiiiiii");

       // populate your list
       list.add(listmodel);

       //now set the adapter..
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
2. If you don't know about the contents and size of the list, especially when you are populating you list from data fetched from some resource over internet or database.. then you may use

   `list.add(listmodel);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

   the code will be like

   ```
       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
       adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       ListModel listmodel = new ListModel();
       listmodel.setName("Hiiiiii");`
       list.add(listmodel);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in the onCreate method as shown below:
The reason is that the data in the list that you are passing to adapter is 0.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.challenges_view);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        ListModel listmodel = new ListModel();
        listmodel.setName("Hiiiiii");
        list.add(listmodel);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Now this will show an item "Hiiiiii" in the list.